# Regex to exclude a single character but allow if more than one characters

Tags: regex

Trying to create regex to not allow a single character of Q or q but allow the Q or q if more than one character.

Tried:

`/^[^Q]|[^q]{0,1}$/`

Example:

```
Q     //no match
q     //no match
Quest //match
Qu    //match
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide what you are trying to accomplish through sample input, expected output? Include samples of what should match and also what should not match.

Comment: `^(?:[^qQ]|.{2,})$`

Comment: `^(?:[^qQ'&quot;]|[^'&quot;]{2,})$` - Why `&quot;`? Also, the `|` will also be prevented if you use `|` inside `[...]`

Comment: its in an html string in quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:[^qQ]|.{2,})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2MMida/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A%5B%5EqQ%5D%7C.%7B2%2C%7D)%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[^qQ]` - any char but `q` or `Q`
  - `|` - or
  - `.{2,}` - any 2 chars (other than linebreak chars for NFA engines)
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - end of string.

To match a string that has no `"` or `'` in it using the regex above, you need to use

```
^(?:[^qQ'"]|[^'"]{2,})$
        ^^  ^^^^^
```

where `[^'"]` matches any char but `'` and `"`.

Comment: still can't get it to work with combined `^[^'|&quot;]*$` to prevent `'` or `"` anywhere in the string

Comment: @BarclayVision Where do you use it? If the problem is in the `&quot;` use `^(?:[^qQ'\x22]|[^'\x22]{2,})$`. [Look at this regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/2MMida/2), it works well. Again, do not use `|` inside  a character class if you do not want to also "exclude" the `|` char.

Comment: the `&quot;` works fine, just need to add your initial example with it. (need to exclude `'` or `"` from anywhere in the string

Comment: @BarclayVision Are you sure these are `"` chars? Aren't there *curly* `“”` quotes? Try `^(?:[^qQ'&quot;“”]|[^'&quot;“”]{2,})$` or `^(?:[^qQ'&quot;“”‘’]|[^'&quot;“”‘’]{2,})$`. If you test on an online Web tester add `\n` to the negated character classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead to assert that standalone letter Qs do not appear:

```
^(?!.*\b[Qq]\b).*$
```

This won't match any input containing a solitary q or Q.

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Anchors (and lookaheads) to the rescue:

```
^(?![qQ]$).+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/LqA9KQ/2/).

Comment: Bingo... that's it. Thanks

Comment: how would I combine that with existing to prevent `"` I have `^[^'|&quot;]*$ `

Answer (score 0):

How about `/^[^Qq]*$|[Qq].*[Qq]/`?
The "|" is or. The lefthand states that no q at all, from start to finish, wheras the right finds 2 occurances.